# Simple for loop to guess variable name in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, iterator, iteration

I am new to python (coming from R) and trying to practice for loops, so I made up this challenge to have the computer guess the `name` string. Unfortunately I have stumped myself. Can anyone offer assistance?

```
## Guess a name

name = 'Kate'
char = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRZTUVWXYZ'

for k in range(len(name)):
 for i in range(len(char)):
  if name[k] == char[i]:
     print('Your name is ' + char[i])
```

This gives the following output:

```
Your name is K
Your name is a
Your name is t
Your name is e
```

But I am looking for:

```
Your name is Kate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the print() call is called every time a character is guessed correctly.
to fix this, I would move the `print("Your name is"...)` function outside of the for loops.  Python also has a way of changing how `print()` ends its lines.

```
...
print("Your name is ", end="")
for k in range(len(name)):
 for i in range(len(char)):
  if name[k] == char[i]:
     print(char[i], end="")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to take a new empty string variable, and add it when the condition is satisfied and then after everything is done, print the variable outside the loop